# Node-RED: how do I get the URL "fragment" within a "HTTP In" node?

Tags: node-red

I'm currently trying to implement a small HTTP(S) server for testing purposes.

Therefore I also need the URL "fragment" (i.e., any text after the "#") of an incoming request.

But, as it seems, the fragment gets swallowed somewhere within Node-RED before it reaches the "HTTP In" node: according to the debug output, both `msg.req._parsedURL.hash` and `msg.req._parsedOriginalURL.hash` are `null`.

So, how do I retrieve the fragment then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers never send the URL fragment to the server, so you cannot access it.

From the [w3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webarch/#media-type-fragid)

> Interpretation of the fragment identifier is performed solely by the agent that dereferences a URI; the fragment identifier is not passed to other systems during the process of retrieval. This means that some intermediaries in Web architecture (such as proxies) have no interaction with fragment identifiers and that redirection (in HTTP [RFC2616], for example) does not account for fragments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't

Fragments are all handled in the browser, that part of the URL is never sent to the backend server.